# How do I request an access token in Angular?

Tags: angular, authorization, token, sap-commerce-cloud

how is it going?

I'm creating this registration form, totally custom, and I have to save the information in the back end but I'm having trouble when trying to authorize my request so the post can be made.

I am following this article: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/05/28/getting-started-with-oauth-2.0-in-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/

Replicating the example in Postman worked fine, my problem is to translate that to Angular.

Here is how I'm trying to achieve this:

```
this.http
        .post(
          'https://~~~/authorizationserver/oauth/token',
          '',
          {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              token_name: 'hybris',
              grant_types: 'Client Credentials',
              client_id: '~~~',
              client_secret: '~~~',
              scope: 'extended',
              client_authentication: 'Send as Basic auth header',
            }),
          }
        )
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            console.log(response);
          },
          (error) => {
            this.error = error.message;
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
```

The ~~~ are only for security. I believe the error is not there, since I can get the token via Postman.

In the browsers console I get an unknown error. In the network tab I get a CORS error, and a 403.

Does anyone can help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't yet configured your CORS policy. You have to allow this specific client to your server. So this is a CORS problem at the first place.

P.S: you should not save your credentials in your angular code